# How to get all web services hosted in IIS using C#

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I need to get the list of **Web Services** hosted on IIS using C#.

How can I ?

Help me.

Comment: Will you please add some more detail? what are you trying to do and why?

Comment: Just I need to list All web services hosted in IIS that's it.

Comment: What do you consider a web service? That could be anything. An aspx page could even be a web service. If you're looking for .svc files or the old style services .asmx (I forget the old extension... i think it's something like that), you could just search the web root?

Comment: I am having .asmx and .svc. i need to get these services as a collection. We can get collection of Windows services using ServiceController. As like this i need to get Web services hosted on IIS.

Comment: Try Using Directory Entries, will allows you to work with virtual directories entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use DirectoryEntries and get the folders listed at

```
         IIS://hostname/W3SVC/1/root
```